# How to fix weird characters in Persian subtitles?

Tags: notepad++, encoding

Sometimes when I add subtitles on movies, it displays some weird characters instead of Persian words.After a few searches I found a software named "per sub fix" and its very good and solve some of my problem but not all.It only supports .srt files. so I still have problem with other subtittle format like .ass or.sub,etcDo you know how to fix these subtitles manually without any software? What does this software do to "fix" the subtitles?

I'm using windows and please don't say change player settings.

I can't fix it with notepad++ trying to change encode

edit:
I forget to upload pics so here is subtittle text contains weird character and before fixing with per sub fix:

[image]

and this is fixed and correct subtittle:

[image]

Comment: If you don't explain what you're actually seeing, what is wrong about it and what isn't working it's going to be a guessing game.

Comment: How a random program actually "works" is a question for the author of that software. Why does Notepad++ not work? Most subtitles are simply text so unless you show us the actual problem there is going to be little we can do to help. Showing us a file from "before" and "after" you process it with this program would be helpful as well as an image showing just what the error is in the first place.

Comment: Did you use the correct option in Notepad++? One changes how Notepad++ interprets the *current* state of the file. The other *converts* this state.

Comment: yes I use both of them and dont work
even I changed encode to arabic but still dont work

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example file/snippet?

Answer (score 5):

This problem is due to wrong encoding used to create the file. You can open the file in notepad++, then choose:

```
Encoding menu > Character set > Arabic > Windows-1256
```

then select:

```
Encoding menu > Convert to UTF-8
```

and finally `File > Save As` to save it as another name.

Let me know if it doesn't work for you. I know persian and I test it with your sample word (ãÏáÔ íå¿ => modelesh chieh?), it successfully converted to utf unicode (مدلش چیه). if you want you can give a sample url to a file you want to fix(convert) such that i can test and say you what should you do.

Comment: realy thanks it works! I think I tried it before but it wasnt working
but now after trying again it works!
thanks alot.

Comment: @user868673 you are welcome! glad to help you, خواهش میکنم ;D